# Set name of all empty field in view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a date/time field name DeliveryDate and I have a view that will list all Delivery date. Some of document will have empty delivery date. Below here the example of the view.

[image: yerro]

Right now, the view show "(Not Categorized)". How can I change it to another name such as "Old Record". Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is change the formula for that view column to e.g.:

@if(DeliveryDate=“”;”Old Record”;DeliveryDate)

Of course you might prefer to remove those records from the view all together. In that case just add the following to the Select formula for the view:

& !DeliveryDate=“”

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the data?  You can't, today.  To understand - you want different text instead of "Not Categorized" to represent empty data?  And that would be at the view level?

Comment: Yes, is it possible? I just want to change different text of "Not Categorized" for empty data, and only change it at view level.